# Convert HTML Rows into Name Value Pair in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to convert an HTML Table to Name-Value pair in JSON format using Jquery.

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
           <tr>
                  <th>MobileNumber</th>
                   <th>Amount</th>
                   <th>Fuel</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>1223445</td>
                  <td>12.49</td>
                  <td>1223</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>99999</td>
                  <td>11.39</td>
                  <td>1277745</td> 
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

The above table  should get converted to a JSON formatted name value pair as below

```
[{
       "Customer":{ 
          "MobileNumber":"1223445"
        },
        "TemplateFieds": [{
           "Name": "Amount",
           "value": "12.49"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Fuel",
             "value": "1223"
         }]
  },
  {
       "Customer":{ 
          "MobileNumber":"99999"
        },
        "TemplateFieds": [{
           "Name": "Amount",
           "value": "11.39"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Fuel",
             "value": "1277745"
         }]
  }]
```

I am trying to modify this function from ([get values from table as key value pairs with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968253/get-values-from-table-as-key-value-pairs-with-jquery)) but I cant get it right.

```
  var result = $('myTable tbody').children().map(function () {
               var children = $(this).children();
                return {
                    name: children.eq(0).text(),
                    value: children.eq(1).text()
                };
               }).get();
```

Anyone has idea to convert the HTML table to above mentioned JSON format?

-Alan-

Comment: What is the logic for deciding whether a column should go into `"Customer"` or `TemplateFields"`? Or is it just an arbitrary rule and the columns will not be subject to change?

Comment: First Column always go to Customer and the rest of the column should go to TemplateFields

Comment: As above for deciding if amount/fuel is a string/number.

Comment: I have edited the question. Everything should be in string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the column names from the `<th>` elements as well and match them via the column index. I also fixed your "TemplateFieds" typo, which should be "TemplateFields". (missing "l")

```js
var colNames = $('.table thead th').get().map(el => el.textContent);
var result = $('.table tbody').children().map(function() {
  var children = $(this).children().get();
  var resultObj = {Customer: {}, TemplateFields: []};
  children.forEach((cell, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      resultObj['Customer'][colNames[index]] = cell.innerText;
    } else {
      resultObj['TemplateFields'].push({
        name: colNames[index],
        value: cell.innerText
      });
    }
  });
  return resultObj;
}).get();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>MobileNumber</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Fuel</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1223445</td>
      <td>12.49</td>
      <td>1223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>99999</td>
      <td>11.39</td>
      <td>1277745</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, loop through the `thead` to get the Name properties:

```
var cols = $("table>thead>tr>th").map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
});
```

then loop through each row `$('table>tbody>tr')` creating an entry to add to your result array and within each row, loop through each cell except the first to generate the name/value pair.

```js
var cols = $("table>thead>tr>th").map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
});

var result = [];

$('table>tbody>tr').each(function() {
  var cells = $(this).find("td");
  var row = {
    Customer: { MobileNumber: cells.first().text() },
    TemplateFieds: []
  };
  cells.each(function(i, e) {
    if (i == 0) return; // skip first col
    row.TemplateFieds.push({
      "Name": cols[i],
      "value": $(this).text()
    })
  });
  result.push(row);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>MobileNumber</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Fuel</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1223445</td>
      <td>12.49</td>
      <td>1223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>99999</td>
      <td>11.39</td>
      <td>1277745</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Couple of notes:

- probably want name/value or Name/Value rather than Name/value
- probably want TemplateFie*l*ds

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

```
let tab = document.getElementById("tab");
let names = tab.querySelectorAll("th");
let values = tab.querySelector("tbody").children;

let arr = [];

for(let i =0; i < values.length;i++){
  let obj = {};
  for(let j = 0;j < names.length;j++){
    obj[names[j].innerHTML] = values[i].children[j].innerHTML;
  }
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

but it's not good solution

Comment: Some explainations might be a good thing, to make sure the author understands your intent, especially if your suggestion isn't actually a good solution in the long run.